Is protecting MOSFET gates with an RC snubber without a TVS diode reliable?
I am currently making a small device similar to the BBC micro:bit and I wanted to use a MOSFET as the main power switch (which the uC controls). However the only problem is that my device is an open PCB so it can be susceptible to ESD from the user's body. I am using JLCPCB's PCBA service and all their TVS diodes are of the "extended components" type which requires an extra fee which I would like to avoid. Can I use an RC snubber (or even just a capacitor like in the schematic as the R is provided by human body) to clamp those ESD events? My application certainly doesn't need high frequency, it only needs to turn on when the device turns on (and vice versa). Here is a suggested schematic, and it seems to work, but am I missing something? The only thing that comes to mind is the cap's ESR, but that is not that significant.
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKswIMxoQFgJwDY8AOLXAJmMJAUipCzSoFMBaMMAKAGMQ1IsRSCPDz49SNfjHiQIU8TgUB2QgoTFcOLMKkyoXAZErijhsRPAswNOVb6pqkHIrxgshRQbh6ATgZOVefmMocAd2AHM-MyiMbT1IwOjE2JDIdgAPcDAGUkUIMEIIXP4gmgBhAH0AIwB7ABMATwyBUnzFD3IccEJzcRAAJWr6poB3EVLKLC9gtMyMLrB8OhVwBToDEABZGoBnADNGABcAHR3wgENDxlOAC0ZvRnZfRMFhF9MaDjnSUgEtHjwOVw6z6AFEAMr9dhAA

Do they have Z-/zener diodes..?

The Vinit and ESR are significant ! https://tinyurl.com/26n4r98v

You can answer this question by yourself with the following info:
A standard ESD test (gun) has a 150pF cap. charged to 2-8kV and an output impedance of 330 Ohm.
With a simulator you can connect the charged cap to your circuit and see how much voltage you get on the gate.
You will easily see that it is not viable from a practical point of view to protect the FET as intended.

Isn't that what my schematic does? The left capacitor is charged to 2kV. The capacitor attached between the MOSFET gate and source absorbs the energy...?

You need 150pF and 330 Ohms. And you need to check the impedance of the cap at ESD pulse frequency/rise time (8ns)

I may be reliable only if it is a low ESR that often have C * ESR = Tau < 10 us.
A better protection is a series R and Schottky diode to DC clamp.
